# Node.js Only downloads part of file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, output

I have a node.js application whose task is to send a file to the client when a specific url is typed in. I am able to send the file from the node.js server to the client but it always stops at 4mb. To my understanding the problem is that the server closes the file before the client can fully download it. What am I doing wrong? and why does it always stop at 4mb?

```
    switch(req.url) {
case '/helloworld/hello.js/test':
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '/files/output.mp3');
    var file = fileSystem.readFileSync(filePath, 'binary');
    var stat = fileSystem.statSync(filePath);

    res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=output');
    res.write(file, 'binary');
    res.end();
  break;
```

Comment: Do you use nginx (or other webserver) in front of node.js?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to use [`createReadStream`](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-read-stream) instead of `readFileSync` because Node.js is single-threaded and blocking operations (like `readFileSync`) may cause unnecessary delays on a production server with highload